# Converting a integer to date

Tags: postgresql

I am having an issue with converting an integer date (20180525) to a date in the format of YYYY-MM-DD. Is there a way to do this or should I just convert it in code (Java in this case)? Any help with this would be most appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: 20180525 - doesn't look like an integer date to me it look s like a string date with no spaces.  what's 20180525-626

Answer (score 14, accepted):

if your dates are stored as integers with YYYYMMDD, you can pass it to the date function by first casting to `TEXT`.

```
SELECT date(20180525::TEXT)
```

otherwise, use the function to_date with a date formatter:

```
SELECT to_date(20180525::text, 'YYYYMMDD')
```

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

Either SQL or Java works well. For SQL, see the [correct Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50532562/642706) by Ali.

For Java, pass a [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) to a [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) query.

```
LocalDate.parse(                      // `LocalDate` represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone. Works with SQL-standard `DATE` type.
    Integer.toString( 20180525 ) ,    // Convert integer to text, for a `String` object as input.
    DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE  // Specify a formatting pattern to match our input string.
)                                     // Returns a `LocalDate` object.
```

> 2018-05-25

## java.time

Regarding Java mentioned in the Question, here is code using the modern *java.time* classes. Whether you should use SQL or Java to parse you string depends on your situation and your tastes, as either route works.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

You need to specify a formatting pattern to match your input. In this particular case, your input string is in standard ISO 8601 format. Specifically, the “basic” variant of ISO 8601 formats that minimize the use of delimiters. In *java.time*, you will find [this particular formatting pattern is conveniently predefined](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#BASIC_ISO_DATE) for you.

```
String input = Integer.toString( 20180525 ) ;  // Convert integer to text for input as `String`. 
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
```

> ld.toString(): 2018-05-25

### JDBC

As of [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) 4.2 and later, you can directly exchange *java.time* objects with your database. Always better to use smart objects rather than dumb strings.

```
String sql = "SELECT event_date FROM tbl WHERE event_date = ? ; " ;
…
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 1 , ld ) ;
```

And retrieval.

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: installing java in postgres just to do this seem like doing it the hard way

Comment: @Jasen No, I am referring to client-side app code. Notice the `String sql` lines.

Answer (score 1):

```
select ((field_int)::text)::date as field_date from your_table;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not correct answer is `to_timestamp(timestamp_int)::date`, but it's really what i was expected to find under this title/question.
Explanation that someone save date as int `20180525` shows that the world is full of incredible ideas