# postgreSQL increment number in output

Tags: postgresql

I am extracting three values (server, region, max(date)) from my postgresql> But I want to extract an additional 4th field which should be the numerical addition of 1 to 3rd field. I am unable to use date add function as in the database date field is defined as an integer.

**date type in DB**

```
date|integer|not null
```

tried using cast and date add function

```
MAX(s.date)::date + cast('1 day' as interval)
```

*Error Received*

```
ERROR:  cannot cast type integer to date
```

Required output

```
select server, region, max(alarm_date), next date from table .....

testserver, europe, 20190901, 20190902
testserver2, europe, 20191001, 20191002
```

next date value should be the addition to alarm_date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First solution that came to my mind:

```
select (20190901::varchar)::date + 1
```

Which output 2019-09-02 as type date.

Other solutions can be found [here](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50532262/postgresql-integer-to-date).

Comment: can i able to get the output without -(hyphens) after adding 1

Comment: This is a bad practice, as the other user suggested.

Anyway, in order to do so:
`select replace((to_date(20190901::text,'YYYYMMDD') + 1)::text,'-','')::integer`

This does replace hyphens and converts back to integer. As if i am correct... you want to update the value. You should really change the type and avoid doing so. Risky and very tricky

Answer (score 2):

To convert an integer like `20190901` to a date, use something like

```
to_date(CAST(s.date AS text), 'YYYYMMDD')
```

It is a bad idea to store dates as integers like that. Using the `date` data type will prevent corrupted data from entering the database, and it will make all operations natural.